# JS reportValidity() bypass try-catch when encounters non-focusable element

Tags: javascript, try-catch

I'm working on a personal project (PHP / JS), and trying to use as many default functionalities from the browser as possible. So, I've tried to validate a HTML form using reportValidity and got this error:

`An invalid form control with name='element-name' is not focusable.`

The HTML element in question really is not visible on the screen, because the form has a filter on it; if the user filters the list, some of the elements will be hidden from view - I completely understand this behaviour, so I tried put reportValidity call on a try-catch statement, like this:

```
    try
    {
        if(frmEdicao.reportValidity())
            frmEdicao.submit();
    }
    catch(oErro)
    {
        alert('Some message to user here');
    }
```

And now the "gotcha" that I don't understand: I keep getting the same error, the try-catch statement seems to have no effect!

Just to be **extremely** clear, I'm conscious that the error is occurring because the HTML element isn't visible (CSS `display` property was set to 'none' by the filter I mentioned already) when I call reportValidity(). What I trying to understand is why the try-catch statement is simply ignored by the browser in this specific case...

I put this silly example on CodePen ([Form validation](https://codepen.io/sidneipaixao/pen/GRejyWV)) if someone wants to try it; note that the error occurs (as expected), but the catch part (supposed to show an alert to the user) simply don't fire. And my test case scenario is an Opera browser (updated) on Windows 10 environment (but I don't think this bit of information is relevant).

As this error is happening only in one (filtered) form, I'll use `checkValidity()` instead for this specific form. But... there are any reasons for this strange behaviour? I really like to know. :)

Comment: Maybe it's not an exception but only a warning?

Comment: @Bergi, seems to me that the browser actually throws an error; I'm not sure, you may be right - since I hadn't get the "Uncaught exception" that commonly starts an error message, even without the try/catch block - but the browser console show the error icon (red "x") on console tab (so, for me, it "feels" like an error; warnings are treated the same by the browser? If so, I think it's very confusing).